# google maps - show current position coordinates

Tags: maps, coordinates

I want to show coordinates from my current position on map. Here is the code and it doesn't work like it should. It only shows map within defined parameters, but when I click on button that shows my current position, nothing happens.
I made this code using Android Studio tutorials on web.
I am using Android studio and just a fresh learner.

This is also what I get in event log when I run the app on my smartphone:

> 21:56:48 Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger
>   21:56:49 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
>            java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
>            at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
>            at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
>            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
>            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
>            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
>            at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
>            at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:686)
>            at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:349)
>            at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:525)
>            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:569)
>            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:544)
>            at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:360)
>            at com.android.ddmlib.Devic...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity_koordinate"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

```
    package com.example.apollo.kartamackovec;

    import android.location.Location;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
    import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    public class MapsActivity_koordinate extends FragmentActivity implements     GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, OnMapReadyCallback, MapsActivity {

    public GoogleMap mMap;

    public GoogleApiClient client;
    public TextView mLongitudeText;
    public TextView mLatitudeText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;


        LatLng mackovec = new LatLng(46.4239, 16.4339);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mackovec).title("Marker u Mačkovcu"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mackovec));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mackovec, 18));
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(client);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location " + mLatitudeText+","+mLongitudeText,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "noconnection",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
        public void onStart() {
            client.connect();
            super.onStart();

            // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
            // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
            client.connect();
            Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                    Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                    "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                    // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                    // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                    // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                    Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                    // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                    Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.apollo.kartamackovec/http/host/path")
            );
            AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            client.disconnect();
            super.onStop();

            // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
            // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
            Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                    Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                    "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                    // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                    // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                    // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                    Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                    // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                    Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.apollo.kartamackovec/http/host/path")
            );
            AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
            client.disconnect();
        }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "noconnection",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work like it should" mean exactly?

Comment: App only shows map like it is initialized in code above, and shows current location, i would like to get current location coordinates in text label.

Comment: @vesan please see last edit of the problem